# given hostname and port how to upload a website

Tags: server, apache2, mysql

So I'm given a hostname along with the port number. I'm trying to run this site on my computer but all i see is default apache2 page.

I have LAMP installed on Ubuntu 18.04. 
Latest version of PMA along with MySQl and PHP. I created a database in mysql through terminal. I then went to PMA and imported the database that i had into freshly created database.

Now i don't know how to launch that website. I have the hostname and the port number. I don't the configuration that I have to do.

Comment: is this site public (internet), local network or just from your same machine?

Comment: hostname and port will get you to the server but not any application running on it unless it's been configured to do so.  is it possible you're missing more to the url... http://somehost:8080/someapp vs just http://somehost:8080

Comment: well the original site is public. I'm using it's database and uploading it to a completely new site. I'm assuming that my my default apache2 page is my new site or should I making a new wordpress site and use the old database and import it into that